# Why does the Facebook Send button pop-up window close?

Tags: facebook, web-scraping, send

We are looking at allowing users to share a link via a few different social media networks. The Tweet, Pin it and LinkedIn share button are each working, but the issue we are encountering revolves around the Facebook Send button.

The button appears to load fine, but when clicked on it puts up a message that "The page at www.website.com/page1.jsp?order_nbr=123456 could not be reached".

When using the object debugger @ the Facebook Developers site, something interesting happens:
Trying to debug  `www.website.com/page1.jsp?order_nbr=123456` the Response code of the scrape is a 502 error (URL returned a bad HTTP response code).
Trying to debug `www.website.com/page1.jsp` we get a 200 (normal response).
Trying to debug `m.website.com/page1.jsp` or `m.website.com/page1.jsp?order_nbr=123456`, both return the same 502 error.

It appears like there is an issue when there are parameters in the URL after the `?`, but then we are wondering if there is something else that needs to be set, or if this might be a server configuration issue.

If there are technical explanations of how facebook scrapes a page, or why their send button might be getting a 502 error, while the others mentioned above are operating normally? Any insight would be appreciated.

Here is the bare bones code we have stripped things down to in order to test on the mobile site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">

<head>
  <title>Testing - Order #123456</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/icon.png" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <link href="/css/test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Test - Order #123456" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://m.website.com/page1.jsp?order_nbr=123456"/>
  <meta property="og:image" content="../../images/mobile_files/logo.png" />

 <!--asynchronous loader-->
 <script src="../../js/init.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

</head>

<body>
      <DIV id="fb-root"></DIV>

  <DIV id="menu">
       <DIV style="float: left; padding:2px; "><fb:send ref="top_left_m" ></fb:send></DIV>  
       <DIV style="float: left; padding:2px;"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none">Tweet</a> </DIV>
       <DIV style="float: left; padding:2px;"> <a data-pin-config="none" data-pin-do="buttonPin" href="//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fm.website.com%2Fjsp%2Forder.jsp%3Fjob_order_id%3D%3C%25%3DjobOrderId%25%3E&media=http%3A%2F%2Fm.website.com%2Fimages%2Fmobile_files%2Flogo.png&description=Testing..."><img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png" /></a> </DIV>
       <DIV style="float: left; padding:2px;"><script type="IN/Share"></script> </DIV>

       <DIV style="clear:both;"></DIV>
</DIV>  

</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: The output of debugger is different than it was the other day, I believe due to a redeploy and/or cached (server and/or local)previous tests, however two main issue remain.
.#1 - The main site is scraping fine (Return code 200). The mobile site returns a 502 and returns nothing.
.#2 - If I am not logged in to Facebook, a pop-up appears asking me to sign in.  Once I do, the window disappears completely.  If I am logged in to Facebook, a pop-up appears briefly and then disappears completely.
.#3 - Parameters in the URL have been ruled out as an issue.

Based on the nature of the biggest issue (#2)... I am going to change my question to be...
"Why does the Facebook Send button pop-up window close?"
(I will break #1 into a separate question if that's more appropriate, but I think the entirety of my problems are best served by leaving everything in one question )

Just in case it's relevant, here is the JS asynch loader:

```
(function(doc, script) {
     var js, 
     fjs = doc.getElementsByTagName(script)[0],
     add = function(url, id) {
     if (doc.getElementById(id)) {return;}
          js = doc.createElement(script);
          js.src = url;
          id && (js.id = id);
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     };
   // Facebook SDK
   add('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1', 'facebook-jssdk');
   // Pinterest
   add('http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js');
   // Twitter SDK 
   add('//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', 'twitter-wjs');
   // LinkedIN
   add('//platform.linkedin.com/in.js');
}(document, 'script'));
```

Comment: What's the output of the `echo` tool on your page? See: `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=<YOUR URL>`

Comment: Output of echo is "Document returned no data" for the three returning 502 errors, and for the main site with no parameter it shows the source for the entire page.

Comment: Since this site is for mobile, are you aware of any user-agent sniffing that's occurring that might stop the server from showing that page?

Comment: I had not considered that.  We could include the FB scraper User-Agent (facebookexternalhit I believe) to test that out, and will try that later today.  The parameter question still remains though, on the main site.  We don't to any UA sniffing there.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I have this reversed.  The main site has UA-sniffing and redirection (though not on page1.jsp main or mobile), and the mobile version doesn't have any sniffing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that Facebook sends a Range Request as part of the request.  Fails if within the range (0-52K), however pages bigger than this range scrape fine.  Seems older versions of Oracle have an issue dealing with the range, so you need to strip Facebook's range request out of the request headers.